# Code Runner using MSVC create a too long string

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I use CodeRunner for VSCode on Windows, so I need to change g++ to MSVC (Visual C++ Compiler).
So I configure `settings.json` for coderunner:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "cmd.exe",
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "cpp": "vcvars64.bat && cl.exe $fileName && del $fileNameWithoutExt.obj && cls && $fileNameWithoutExt.exe",
    },
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay"
}
```

As you can see, I add path of vcvars64.bat to system PATH.
It works, but after several runs I get next error:

> Input line is too long.

I search for it and found that it is because CodeRunner run vcvars64.bat every time! So after several runs total path become too long:

["Input line is too long" error in BAT File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821784/input-line-is-too-long-error-in-bat-file)

Restarting console clear it, but after several runs falls again.

Looks like I need to find some way to use `vcvars64.bat` only once but I don't know how!

Comment: Run `vsvars64.bat` in your command prompt first, then run coderunner from that command prompt (Visual Studio adds a shortcut to do this: Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2019 (or similar))

Answer (score 1):

This is my setting.json

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "cpp": "cd $dir && cl /EHsc $fileName && cls && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt.exe && del 
  $dir$fileNameWithoutExt.obj $dir$fileNameWithoutExt.exe",
},
```

And it's **working as expected**.

Comment: Thank you for responce! It's work, but I need to use `vcvars64.bat` first time manually. How to use it automatically? In my example I use `vcvars64.bat` in `code-runner.executorMap` and it is a matter of error.

Comment: don't know y it's not working in cmd but it working fine in powerShell.

Answer (score 1):

**change** default shell to **PowerShell** in vs-code

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
```

then **add this** in **setting.json** file :

**For PowerShell**

```
"cpp": "cd $dir ; vcvars64.bat ;  cl /EHsc $fileName ; ./$fileNameWithoutExt.exe",
```