# Windows - "The command line is too long" when building .obj files

Tags: windows, cmd, linker, scons, object-files

I am quite a novice user with the compiler based projects.

Before posting this question, I got across few similar questions in SO community as below

[SO: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805590/the-command-line-is-too-long-when-linking-obj-files-in-windows-command-prompt)

[SO: 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821784/input-line-is-too-long-error-in-bat-file)

I am trying to build the obj files from the build.cmd in command prompt as

```
build.cmd Target_Machine
```

It is building the .c and .h files but, when building the .obj files it is giving me the below error

```
"Command line is too long".

Scons: Building terminated because of errors
```

How to overcome this issue?

Comment: I would guess that `build.cmd` joins together, as argument(s), all of your `.obj` files. `cmd.exe` only allows for strings up to `8191` characters for a post [tag:windows-xp] OS, _(`2047` for pre [tag:windows-xp] OS)_. The fixes would be, if your `.obj` files being processed include their paths, then move them to a different location, or otherwise shorten their paths; or if they're named with long names, shorten their names. Alternatively if the processing executable accepts a file as input, modify the script to send the `.obj` files to a file and pass that file in as input instead.

Comment: What package are you trying to build? build.cmd is not the "native" way to launch scons?

Answer (score 2):

There's support for breaking up command lines using TempFileMunge. There's some material on it in the wiki:

https://github.com/SCons/scons/wiki/LongCmdLinesOnWin32

there doesn't seem to be much in the "official documentation", which is a little surprising since I thought this kicked in automatically on Windows. Do look at `MAXLINELENGTH` in the manpage.